# Failed to call the method because [Sitecore.Data.Items.Item] does not contain a method named "op_Addition"

Tags: powershell

I am trying to execute this script but it is throwing an error.

```
$path = "/sitecore/content/home"
$root = Get-Item $path
$items = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse
($items += $root) | Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -eq "Product" -or $_.TemplateName -eq "Accessory" } | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Log "Hi"
}
```

This part is throwing an error: `($items += $root)`.

**Error**:

> Failed to call the method because [Sitecore.Data.Items.Item] does not contain a method named "op_Addition"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Marek's answer is correct and addresses the error, but it's worth bearing in mind that in the situation posted, you have a simpler option available to you:

```
$path = "/sitecore/content/home"
$items = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -WithParent
```

The `-WithParent` parameter will automatically include the root item for you.

Answer (score 4):

Your code works ok when there are multiple items returned from `Get-ChildItem` command.

If only 1 item is returned, SPE returns single item object instead of an array.

You can work around the issue by wrapping both `$root` and `$items` variables with `@(...)` like:

```
$path = "/sitecore/content/home"
$root = @(Get-Item $path)
$items = @(Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse)
($items += $root) | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name
}
```